# How to ordering name of month in MySQL & PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a query for showing my database :

```
    SELECT archieve, SUM(items_in) AS income, SUM(items_out+black_out+white_out) AS outcome, SUM((ball_out+black_out+white_out
    )-items_in) AS efficiency, SUM((items_in / ( ball_out + black_out + white_out))*100) AS percent 
    FROM items 
    GROUP BY archieve
ORDER BY DATE_FORMAT(archieve,'%m')
```

my archieve table just content month and year of data when it's submitted. For example :

```
Jan 2014, Feb 2014, Mar 2014
```

but what showed in my page is :

```
Feb 2014, Jan 2014, Mar 2014
```

This my php code to insert data from my web into database :

```
$date_trans = date("d M Y");
$archieve   = date("M Y");
$items_in   = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['items_in']);
$ball_out   = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['ball_out']);
$black_out  = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['black_out']);
$white_out  = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['white_out']);
$ball   = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['ball']);
$black  = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['black']);
$white  = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['white']);
$note   = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['note']);
```

Everything's fine with the code, but how to make it ordered well by month? Because I've tried with MONTH(date) or date.(MONTH) it doesn't work. Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: can we see your table structure please

Comment: You need to sort first by *year*, then by the *number* of the month. What you sort by and what you display don't need to be the same thing

Comment: sorry I forget to copy `ORDER BY (archieve,'%m')` after GROUP BY @MikeSherrill'CatRecall'

Comment: Because `F` is before `J` in the alphabet, and `J` is before `M`?

Comment: @Satya maybe my edited post can help :D

Comment: @h2ooooooo nooo, because when there are Feb, Mar and Apr. It is showed Feb, Apr and Mar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert your string "archieve" to date first, and then sort by the value.
Try this:

```
ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(archieve, '%M %Y')
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
   ORDER BY FIELD(archieve,'Jan','Feb','Mar',...)
```

or this

```
  ORDER BY FIELD(DATE_FORMAT(archieve,'%m'),'01','02','03',...)
```

Comment: when I use word 'date', my page doesn't show the data, but when I didn't use word 'date', the results are still random hmm...

Comment: this date is your column , you should change it. try also that edited answer.

Comment: I've tried, but oh God the results are still random. I have 3 months of data, there are Jan 2014, Mar 2014 and Apr 2014. But Apr 2014 is always show in the 2nd rows hmmm